# Kotlin extension function - How to make it global?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-extension

I have created a Kotlin extension function on the Android `ViewGroup` class so that it can do layout inflation calls easier. So, here is my extension:

```
fun ViewGroup.inflate(layoutRes: Int): View {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layoutRes, this, false)
}
```

and then I can use it like this in an adapter class to inflate a layout:

```
 override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val v = parent.inflate(R.layout.view_item)
    return ViewHolder(v)
}
```

I have declared this extension in the adapter class I am using for a RecyclerView so that it can make inflation calls easier. But I want ALL adapters or I should say all `ViewGroup` classes to see this extension. I want it permanent.

It seems to just stick within where I declared it not globally.  Where should I declare this extension so that anytime I use a view group this method extension will be available?

Comment: i dont think i need to pass in a context. ViewGroup already has a context, getContext(). so it should use its own context.  What you have created is a package level function with no class.  i guess i can put utils in here .  thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make extension funtion global by declaring in object class as shown below:

```
object ViewExtension{

 fun Spinner.validate(): Boolean  {
    if(!this.isSelected){
        this.setSpinnerHint(this.context.getString(R.string.please_select))
        return false
    }
    return true
 }

 fun TextInputLayout.validate(): Boolean{
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(editText?.text)){
        this.error =  this.context.getString(R.string.required)
        return false
    }
    return true
 }
}
```

***How to use extension funtions***

```
fun validateFields(): Boolean{
    var allSelected = true

    textInput.validate().apply {
        if(!this)
            allSelected = false
    }
    
    spinner.validate().apply {
        if(!this)
            allSelected = false
    }

 }
```

Also we need to import the validate method before we use it any class :

```
import com.example.ViewExtension.validate
```

Answer (score 4):

**Problems:**

If you define extension function here (1), it will be accessible globally, but this is bad style since this is the class file of (a special adapter) `MyArrayAdapter` and `inflate` is meant to be used project-wide.

If you define the extension function here (2), it will be only accessible in the context of `MyArrayAdapter`.

```
// (1)
class MyArrayAdapter: ArrayAdapter<String> {
   // (2)
}
```

**What I would do:**

Create a file *Util.kt* with only top-level declarations which serve as utilities.

This is what your *Util.kt* file would look like:

```
package com.yourpackagepath // package in which Utils.kt resides

// written with expression body, which makes it more concise
fun ViewGroup.inflate(layoutRes: Int) = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(layoutRes, this, false)
```

This way the extension is available project-wide and it is good style, because *Util.kt* implies global utilities meant to be used everywhere.

You would call it like this:

```
val v = parent.inflate(R.layout.view_item)
```

If you don't use it in the same package, import it like this:

```
import com.yourpackagepath.inflate
```

Comment: brilliant answer  searching for the same for a very long time

Comment: @SakshamKhurana glad it helped you!

Answer (score 1):

> I have declared this extension in the adapter class i am using for a recyclerview so that it can make inflation calls more easier.

Like this, it is only usable in the context of the adapter class.

Either declare it on package level (**top-level**) or consider defining an object containing the extension:

```
object ViewGroupExt {
    //extensions go here
}
```

Now on the caller side you need to bring `ViewGroupExt` into scope:

```
with(ViewGroupExt){
   //call extensions
}
```

This, compared to the package-level declaration, has the advantage that its access has to be made *explicit*.

Comment: i tested this and it works. i wish there was a way not to use the with closure.  i know it makes it explicit but sometimes i want to add functionality for all class uses and not use with closure. if you think of anyway, let me know. i saw the other answer tried to use your solution without the with closure but it wasn't working for me.

Comment: if i declare it as package level then do i still need to use the with closure ?

Comment: No you don’t. But you have to import it into other classes